# Is this a good eager loading optimization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

After installing the [Bullet gem](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet), I started tackling a couple of n+1 concerns.

I was previously using the safe navigation operator to check the current subscription of the account belonging to current_user:

```
def current_subscription
  @current_subscription ||= current_user&.account&.subscription #n+1 scenario
  @current_subscription
end
```

I refactored with a fresh query using .try():

```
def current_subscription
  @current_subscription ||= Subscription.where(account_id: current_user.try(:account_id)).first
  @current_subscription
end
```

This seems to work fine: my tests still pass and Bullet is satisfied.

Is this good practice or there a better approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need this second `@current_subscription`, its value will be returned from `current_subscription` method anyway. It might not work if you have any `Subscription` with `account_id` being `null` There's a method called `find_by` in ActiveRecord, which does what you're trying to do:

```
def current_subscription
  @current_subscription ||= Subscription.find_by(account_id: current_user&.account_id)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that's much cleaner.